# How to Shuffle & Echo 2 Random word from 2 lines?

Tags: php, arrays, string, explode, shuffle

How to Shuffle & Echo 2 Random word from 2 lines?

example my code

```
$lines1 = "one, two, three, four, five"; 
$lines2 = "aa, bb, cc, dd, ee"; 
$array=explode(",",$lines1, $lines2);  
shuffle($array);  
$newstring = implode($array,""); 
echo substr($newstring, 0, 1);
```

`$lines1` `$lines2`  the original string

echo selective shuffle of 2 word from `line1` and `line2`

i want something like this

`two` this word come from `line1`

`dd` this word come from `line2`

Output `two dd` OR `ee three`

Answer (score 1):

Just explode the two lines in to seprate arrays and then shuffle them. Something like this:

```
$lines1 = "one, two, three, four, five"; 
$lines2 = "aa, bb, cc, dd, ee"; 

$array1 = explode(",", $lines1);  
shuffle($array1);  

$array2 = explode(",", $lines2);  
shuffle($array2);  

echo $array1[0] ." ". $array2[0];
```

Comment: Now work i add extra code

`$myarray = explode(",", $array1[0] .",". $array2[0]);`

`shuffle($myarray);`

`echo $myarray[0] ." ". $myarray[1];`